# all string combinations in a fixed length, based on a charset

Tags: php, math, combinations

I'm looking to create a function that will return every possible string within a given string length, using a charset.

As an example, a charset of "abc", and a length of 2 should allow for 9 (3 ^ 2) unique combinations:

aa,
ab,
ac,
ba,
bb,
bc,
ca,
cb,
cc

(List constructed manually)

What method could be used to create such a function?

Comment: Is this homework or an interview question?  Please tag it accordingly if it is.  We're happy to help, but please help us understand why you're asking.  Thanks.

Comment: @bryc Can combinations like ac and ca be skipped? That is, only unique combos?

Comment: @hakre it is not permutations that the asker seeks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, there are multiple ways to solve what you ask for, this is only one way, using one counter per character in the output string:

```
$c = "abc"; // charset
$l = 2; // string length

for($t='',$cl=strlen($c),$s=array_fill(0,$l,0),$i=pow($cl,$l);$a=0,$i--;) {
    for($t&&$t.=', ';$a<$l;$t.=$c[$s[$a++]]);
    for(;$a--&&++$s[$a]==$cl;$s[$a]=0);
};

echo $t; // the string you asked for.
```

aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc

One main loop, one loop to build the string and one loop for counting up.

I can imagine this should work with getting modulos per each position of the output string as well.

Comment: hello, i upvoted your answer because it is short and quite fitting my needs. however, it is so short, i am not able to change it so i turn it into a function, and then it returns ONE string per call, instead of all possibilities at once. Could you maybe help me with that? or guide me so i can do it? thanks

Answer (score 2):

You already ***did*** go about this, as we can plainly see from your example solution:

aa, ab, ac, ba, bb, bc, ca, cb, cc

What did you do in your head to come up with this solution? You had to keep a few things in mind:

1. what's the char I should start with from charset?
2. as I am constructing the output string, what's the *next* char from charset?
3. how many chars am I allowed to pick from charset?
4. what must I do when I've picked from charset all the chars that I'm allowed to?
5. have I exhausted charset with respect to chars I can start with? if yes, I'm finished.

Can you translate this into code? Or is this answer just too cutesy?

Comment: I suppose you're right, but I'm at a loss when translating it into code -- i.e. how to set up the loop, iterate over the charset etc.

Comment: @bryc: I added some code, see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7863781/all-string-combinations-in-a-fixed-length-based-on-a-charset/7891640#7891640).